# Same serial number is generating for different requests

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am inserting a serial number in a table that is increment by one always but when multiple request is coming in same time it is inserting same serial number for different requests.I am using mysql database.

I know i am fetching the max serial number too early in the code and if request is come in same time so it will fetching same serial number for both. is it good idea to update serial number after all work done. what if inserting a record for new request and updating the serial number for previous one is in same time.

```
public function add(){
    $session          = $this->request->session();

    $company_id       = $session->read('Admin.company_id');
    $emp_id           = $session->read('Admin.emp_id');
    $user_email_id           = $session->read('Admin.email_id');
    $employee_name           = $session->read('Admin.employee_name');

    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        try{

                $conn->begin();   
                $department = $this->request->data['department'];
                $data = $this->request->data;

                if(!array_key_exists('is_requisition_for_contractor', $data)){
                    $is_requisition_for_contractor = 0;
                } else {
                    $is_requisition_for_contractor = $data['is_requisition_for_contractor'];
                }

                if(!array_key_exists('is_requisition_for_employee', $data)){
                    $is_requisition_for_employee = 0;
                } else {
                    $is_requisition_for_employee = $data['is_requisition_for_employee'];
                }

                if(!array_key_exists('is_boulder_requisition', $data)){

                    $is_requisition_for_boulder = 0;
                } else {
                    if($data['is_boulder_requisition'] == ''){
                        $is_requisition_for_boulder = 0;
                    } else {
                        $is_requisition_for_boulder = $data['is_boulder_requisition'];
                    }
                }
                $is_requisition_for_plant = 0;
                if(!array_key_exists('is_plant_requisition', $data)){

                    $is_requisition_for_plant = 0;
                } else {
                    if($data['is_plant_requisition'] == ''){
                        $is_requisition_for_plant = 0;
                    } else {
                        $is_requisition_for_plant = $data['is_plant_requisition'];
                    }
                }

                if(array_key_exists("files",$this->request->data)) {
                    $files      = $this->request->data['files'];

                    if (count($files)) {
                        $files_uploading_response = $this->uploadMultipleFiles($files, 'files/requisitions/');
                    }
                }
                $last_material_insert_id = '';
                if($this->request->data('material_id')[0] == ''){
                    if($this->request->data('department') == 1){
                        $type = 1;
                    } elseif($this->request->data('department') == 3){
                        $type = 3;
                    } elseif($this->request->data('department') == 2){
                        $type = 2;
                    }
                    if($this->request->data('department') == 1 || $this->request->data('department') == 3){
                        $conn->execute("INSERT INTO material (material_name, material_type_id, company_id, status, is_approved_by_admin) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",[$this->request->data('material_name'), $type, $company_id, 1,0]);
                        $last_material_insert_id = $conn->execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id")->fetchAll('assoc');
                    } elseif($this->request->data('department') == 2) {

                        //todo for unapproved material
                        $conn->execute("INSERT INTO material (part_no, material_type_id, company_id, status, is_approved_by_admin,unique_category_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",[$this->request->data('part_no')[0], $type, $company_id, 1,0,$this->request->data('unique_category_id')[0]]);
                        $last_material_insert_id = $conn->execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id")->fetchAll('assoc');
                    }

                }
                // here i am fatching max serial number from table
                $requistion_number          = $conn->execute("SELECT IF(MAX(requisition_no) IS NULL, 0,MAX(requisition_no))  AS requisition_no FROM requisition WHERE site_id = ?",[$this->request->data('site_id')])->fetchAll('assoc');
                $Requisition                = TableRegistry::get('requisition');
                $requisition                = $Requisition->newEntity();
                $requisition->registered_on = $this->request->data['date'];
                $requisition->department_id = $this->request->data('department');
                $requisition->site_id = $this->request->data('site_id');
                $requisition->issues_to_id = $this->request->data['prepared_by_id'];
                $requisition->prepared_by_id = $this->request->data['prepared_by_id'];
                $requisition->approved_by_id = $this->request->data['hod_id'];
                $requisition->hod_id         = $this->request->data['hod_id'];
                $requisition->is_diesel_requisition_for_employee = $is_requisition_for_employee;
                $requisition->is_diesel_requisition_for_contractor = $is_requisition_for_contractor;
                $requisition->is_requisition_for_boulder         = $is_requisition_for_boulder;
                $requisition->is_requisition_for_plant = $is_requisition_for_plant;
                if(array_key_exists('for_tanker_stock', $this->request->data))    {
                    $requisition->for_tanker_stock         = 1;
                }
                if($last_material_insert_id != ''){
                    $requisition->is_material_approved_by_admin = 0;
                }
                $requisition->status         = 1;
                $site_id                     = $this->request->data['site_id'];
                $requisition->requisition_no = $requistion_number[0]['requisition_no'] + 1;
                $requistionnumber = $requistion_number[0]['requisition_no'] + 1;


                $saveRequsition = $Requisition->save($requisition);
                $conn->commit();
}
```

I am expecting the output different serial number for each request.any optimise way to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: You could lock the `requisition` table between the fetching of the maximum `requisition_no` and the insert of the new row, but it would make more sense if `requisition_no` was an auto increment field.

Comment: thanks for the comment.if i lock the table it will slow down the speed of application and i have already one primary key that is auto increment.

Comment: And that primary key is not a good replacement for `requisition_no`?

Comment: this method is basically add requisition for a site for different site it will again start from 1 so i can't replace with primary key .

Comment: Ok, I get it. Another strategy would be to insert the row, in the `requisition` table, without setting the `requisition_no`. Then afterwards you count the numbers of rows, in the `requisition` table, for the site the requisition is for, before the requisition row itself, using the primary key to order the data, and update the `requisition_no` with that figure. Sorry about that complex sentence. Basically you determine the `requisition_no` after the row has been created and given its place in the table.

Comment: that exactly what i do after i found this bug but is it the 100% full proof way to do this.if two request fetching the max serial number  in same time they both get same serial number. and i can't  count rows because in middle some requisitions can be deleted as well.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you totally get my idea. It is somewhat difficult to explain. I'll use an answer to illustrate it with a few queries.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ok please share

Comment: Problem: I don't know what the primary key of the `requisition` table is. Can you tell me?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requisition` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `requisition_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `approved_by_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '0->soft delete 1->open 2->approved 3->reject  4->indent',
  `is_daily_requisition` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0->no 1->yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: this is my table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how about the same strategy, setting the `$requisition_number` after the row has been inserted (see my other answer), but using a single query with the same method you use to determine the new requisition id:

```
$conn->execute("UPDATE requisition 
                SET requisition_no = (SELECT IF(MAX(requisition_no) IS NULL, 0,MAX(requisition_no)) AS requisition_no FROM requisition WHERE site_id = ?) + 1",
               [$this->request->data('site_id')]);
```

The idea here is that a single query will be executed in one step, without another, similar query, being able to interfere.

Comment: may be this will fix the issue i have change my code that way just one error in your code that is
You can't specify target table 'requisition' for update in FROM clause. 
i just nesting the subquery deeper into a from clause and it works.

Answer (score 0):

What you currently do is to first get the old requistion number like this:

```
$requistion_number = $conn->execute("SELECT IF(MAX(requisition_no) IS NULL, 0,MAX(requisition_no)) AS requisition_no 
                                     FROM requisition WHERE site_id = ?",[$this->request->data('site_id')])->fetchAll('assoc');
```

and then increase it before you save and commit.

My suggestion is to *not set* the `$requistion_number` at all before you save and commit the requisition row, but to determine the `$requistion_number` afterwards.

You now wonder how?

Well, you need to count the total number of requisition rows in the table for the site the requisition is for, and add one, like this:

```
$last_requisition_id = $conn->execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id")->fetchAll('assoc');
$site_id = $this->request->data('site_id');
$requisition_number = $conn->execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS requisitionsCount 
                                      FROM requisition
                                      WHERE <primary_key> <= ? AND
                                            site_id = ?",
                                      [$last_requisition_id, $site_id]) + 1;
$conn->execute("UPDATE requisition 
                SET requisition_no = ?
                WHERE <primary_key> <= ?",
               [$requisition_number, $last_requisition_id]);
```

I know this code is not working. The `$requisition_number` will probably contain an array with the `requisitionsCount` as a value, but you can correct that.

Because you're using data that is already present in the database table you don't run the risk that two rows will get the same `$requisition_number`. *The assumption here is that requisitions are never deleted.*

Comment: requisition can be deleted

Comment: @Jeevan What a bummer. I had a new idea.... see the other answer. But then I am really out of ideas.